# How to do function based on ListPickerItem Selection in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, listpicker

I have a ListPicker in my xaml code, and it contains more than ListPickerItem, I want to show a pushpin on my map according to which ListPickerItem is selected.

That's my XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Foreground="white" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="OptionSelection" Margin="0,18,0,0" SelectionChanged="Picker">
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Tag="1" x:Name="Option1" Content="Item1"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Tag="2" x:Name="Option2" Content="Item2"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Tag="3" x:Name="Option3" Content="Item3"/>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And here is my CS code for the SelectionChanged event:

```
private void Picker(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var tag = ((ListPickerItem)OptionSelection.SelectedItem).Tag;

            if (tag.Equals(1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item1 selected"); //I will replace this with my geolocation function later.
            }

        }
```

Mainly I want to know how to apply if statement on my code, that will help me add the geolocation function based on selected item.

Comment: whats the problem here?

Comment: It gives an exception, detailed here

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DataBoundApp3.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement to execute code based on user selection looks fine, except value of `Tag` in this case is a string so you should've compared it to another string (`"1"`) instead of integer (`1`).

The exception you got seems thrown when value of `SelectedItem` is null. You can try to add simple checking at the beginning of the function to handle this condition properly and avoid `NullReferenceException` :

```
private void Picker(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(OptionSelection.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        //do some logic to handle null condition
        //or simply exit the function if there is no logic to be done :
        return;
    }
    var tag = ((ListPickerItem)OptionSelection.SelectedItem).Tag;
    //value of Tag is a string according to your XAML
    if (tag.Equals("1"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item1 selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that half of the problem has been solved ! well, it gives me now an exception that OptionSelection = Null (your code with no edit)

Comment: I have replaced : if(OptionSelection.SelectedItem == null) with: if (OptionSelection == null), that worked for me thanks for your help !